# Qt setting text under tool button

Tags: qt, qt4

I want to show text for the tool button icons using setToolButtonStyle(Qt::ToolButtonTextUnderIcon);

I can see the text for actions directly added to Toolbar (Close & Save), but not for an action(Load) that is added to a QMenu in a Toolbutton. I have added this action in Qmenu to work it as a toggle with other actions(recent files).

I tried to set the text for the Toolbutton too using setText() and setWindowIconText(), but it doesn't work. This is how it looks right now.

[image: Text under icon not working]

Below is the code snippet for the same.

```
actionLoad = new QAction(QIcon(QString("%1/cn_open.png").arg(imageDir)),tr("Load"), this);
actionLoad->setShortcut(tr("Ctrl+L"));
actionLoad->setStatusTip(tr("Load the model"));
connect(actionLoad, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(loadModelDlg()));

actionClose = new QAction(QIcon(QString("%1/cn_close.png").arg(imageDir)),tr("Close"), this);
actionClose->setShortcut(tr("Ctrl+X"));
actionClose->setStatusTip(tr("Close the Model"));
connect(actionClose, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(closeModel()));

actionSave = new QAction(QIcon(QString("%1/cn_save.png").arg(imageDir)),tr("Save"), this);
actionSave->setShortcut(tr("Ctrl+S"));
actionSave->setStatusTip(tr("Save the Model"));
connect(actionSave, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(saveModel()));

m_FileToolBar = addToolBar(tr("File"));
// Show text under the icon in toolbar
m_FileToolBar->setToolButtonStyle(Qt::ToolButtonTextUnderIcon);

// Add a menu for recent file items
m_FileMenu     = new QMenu();
m_FileMenu->addAction(actionLoad); // Add load button as the first item
for (int i = 0; i < MaxRecentFiles; ++i)
  m_FileMenu->addAction(recentFileActions[i]);
updateRecentFileActions();

// Create a tool button. Load button and recent files will be added as a drop down menu
m_FileToolButton = new QToolButton();
m_FileToolButton->setText(tr("Load")); // Not working
m_FileToolButton->setWindowIconText(tr("Load")); // Not working
m_FileToolButton->setMenu(m_FileMenu);
m_FileToolButton->setDefaultAction(actionLoad); 

// This creates a dropdown arrow to click.
m_FileToolButton->setPopupMode(QToolButton::MenuButtonPopup); 

m_FileToolBar->addWidget(m_FileToolButton);

// These actions show text under the icon
m_FileToolBar->addAction(actionClose); 
m_FileToolBar->addAction(actionSave);
```

Any help to resolve this is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you try something like that:

```
    QToolBar bar;
    QToolButton button;

    button.setPopupMode(QToolButton::MenuButtonPopup);
    button.setToolButtonStyle(Qt::ToolButtonTextUnderIcon);

    QAction loadAction(QIcon(":/img/openfile"),"Load",&button);
    button.addAction(&loadAction);
    button.setDefaultAction(&loadAction);

    QAction loadAction2("Load 2",&button);
    button.addAction(&loadAction2);

    bar.addWidget(&button);
    bar.show();
```

I didn't use a QMenu as you can see above.